# How to add a file to fal which was uploaded via ftp

Tags: typo3

in a scheduler action i need to add files to FAL (to sys_file) which are already in the storage, uploaded via ftp. The normal way

```
storage->addFile(....)
```

which copies the file from a temporary folder to the file storage and adds it to the sys_file table does not work, because the file is already in the fileadmin directory. If i try i get this error message:

[ERROR] Cannot add a file that is already part of this storage.

How is it possible to add a file to sys_file which is already in fileadmin?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure, what's the intention... If TYPO3 already knows the file ("a file that is already part of this storage"), why do you want to add it a second time? Maybe moving/copying the file solves your issue. Or just setting a reference?

Comment: The file lies on the server because it was uploaded via FTP. The problem is, that TYPO3 does not know it now: TYPO3 never knows files which are not uploaded in the backend.

Comment: As Jo already wrote, `addFile` adds a file from the local server hard disk to a given path in TYPO3s virtual file system. In your case, there's no need to add the file to the file system anymore - that was already done by FTP. What you're looking for is getting the file indexed, e.g. by regularly running task "File Abstraction Layer: Update storage index"

Comment: Hello Julian, this does not work for me. I am importing a xml feed with news entries. The feed contains filenames which are uploaded via ftp. So i need to add the file to the index and use the resulting FAL-Object to add the files to the imported news entry.

Comment: Ehm, but it would be possible to index the uploaded files before importing the XML feed. So at the time of processing the import, the files are already in the storage and indexed => FAL-Object is available.

Comment: @lisardo; did you ever find a solution for this? I'm currently struggling with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `addFile()` is to be used for files uploaded from a local disk. If the files are already available on the remote server, you should go for `addUploadedFile()` instead.

Comment: Yes, `addFile()` description is "Adds a file from the local server hard disk to a given path in TYPO3s virtual file system.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the newest issue, but after struggling with this myself, I thought this might helpful to others as well.

If you know the folder (within the storage) and name of your file, you can just do this:

```
$folder = $storage->getFolder('/my-dir/');
$file = $storage->getFileInFolder('my-file.txt', $folder);
```

If no `sys_file` record exists, it will be created by doing this. Nothing else to do.

If the physical file existed before, but was updated (e.g. by an FTP upload), just fetching the file will not update the `sys_file` record (timestamp, size etc.).
In that case, you can use the returned File object to simply update the index:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Index\Indexer;
$indexer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Indexer::class, $storage);
$indexer->updateIndexEntry($file);
```

In my case, I simply compare the lastmod times of the file on the file system and the `sys_file` record to find out, whether I need to update the index:

```
if ( $file->getCreationTime() != filemtime($fileWithFullPath) ) {
    // update index
}
```